# Latest WhatsApp desktop application has look & feel of Playstore "App" than Classic Windows application. Have they stopped the other kind?

Tags: windows, windows-10, styles, whatsapp, visual-styles

I had downloaded the WhatsApp Windows Desktop App from Whatsapp website & was using it. It had the Classic Windows Application Look & Fee.

Yesterday, it forced me to upgrade it but during the upgrade process, it went to the Microsoft Store & installed the new WhatsApp version 2.2311.3.0 from there.

This one has the funny Microsoft Store App look & feel which I dislike. It seems to be same one which is available here also - https://www.whatsapp.com/download

Have WhatsApp stopped publishing the Classic Desktop style app & now only publishing the Microsoft Store kind?

I am on Windows 10 Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.2604)

Comment: “Have WhatsApp stopped publishing the Classic Desktop style app & now only publishing the Playstore kind?” - Yes; It’s not called the “Windows Playstore” by the way.

Comment: IIRC the 'old' whatsapp app was electron based and essentially a webapp, and the windows store one's native, strangely enough

Answer (score 0):

Same dislike here!  : )
The MS Store version doesn't allow to download several images together as the previous desktop version does, for example. Only for that detail it is not useful for me.
I deleted it and re-installed the desktop version 2.2310.5 much better!  : )

Comment: Where did you find Desktop version 2.2310.5 for download?